# Where do I get 32 bit Linux kernel source for x86

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am new to Linux Kernel and wanted to have 32 bit Linux Kernel source for x86 arcthitecture but when I download it from kernel.org its gives me source for x86_64 which is not what I required .I am Specially  looking for 3.4.28 version.

Or I have to build 32 bit x86 Linux using x86_64 source only .

Comment: Download the standard Linux kernel code and configure it appropriately....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no specific 32 bit linux kernel source. All architectures are contained in the same tarball / git repository.

The majority of the linux kernel is implemented in portable C which can be used on all architectures. The architecture specific parts are in separate sub directories below the `arch` directory. See also https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/arch.

When configuring and compiling on a `x86_64` machine, you will get an `x86_64` kernel by default. If you want to build a 32 bit `x86` kernel on the same machine, you need to [cross-compile](http://tinkering-is-fun.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/compiling-linux-kernel-for-x86-on-x8664.html), for example:

```
# make ARCH=i386 menuconfig
```

will give you the necessary options to select an x86 based processor type.

```
# make ARCH=i386
```

will then build the x86 based kernel image.

Comment: Yes Andreas I looked into that showing different intel processor family but no support for 32 bit from menuconfig.

Comment: Thanks Andeas for your Help now I Can see x86 option through meanuconfig but getting errors while building looks like have to do some more tweak with respect to tool chain

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for 
http://stacklet.com/downloads/kernels/xen/xenU-2.6.31

or try this
http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/opensuse/updates/12.2/noarch/kernel-source-3.4.28-2.20.1.noarch.html

Comment: Not sure because I am looking particular for 3.4.28 version

Answer (score 1):

If you download the kernel sources at https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.4.28.tar.gz you can compile those for x86 to generate 32 bit binaries.  You can use the same kernel source to generate binaries for different architectures (x86, x86_64, PPC, etc.).  See https://www.kernel.org/doc/index-old.html#Cross_compiling_vs_native_compiling.

Answer (score 1):

See [kernel source](https://www.kernel.org/). Also, take a look on [reading the Linux kernel sources](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Reading_the_Linux_Kernel_Sources).